# Sql query to sort data on one column only but not change the others columns

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I want a SQL query to display the following data

```
ID Name
1  AAA
2  BBB
3  CCC
4  DDD
```

as this:

```
ID Name
4  AAA
3  BBB
2  CCC
1  DDD
```

without changing the other columns.

Kindly suggest?

Thanks

Comment: Can u past here query ure using? And explain what do u exacly need?

Comment: Not clear what you want.... and I don't think you can do this in SQL - sort one column, but leave another one unchanged.... when you apply an `ORDER BY` to a SQL statement, you sort *the entire row* by that criteria.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going with something like this :

```
SELECT t2.ID, t1.NAME
FROM
    (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ID DESC) AS rownumber,
           Name
    FROM MyTable) as t1
    INNER JOIN
        (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ID ASC) AS rownumber,
                ID
         FROM MyTable) as t2
ON t1.rownumber = t2.rownumber
```

You have to set to each row a number for the Name field, and for the ID field, in different order, and then join between them to retrieve the datas in different order.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `row_number` to number the table in two directions, and zip those together:

```
declare @t table (id int, name varchar(4))
insert @t values (1, 'AAA'), (2, 'BBB'), (3, 'CCC'), (4, 'DDD')

; with  numbered as
        (
        select  row_number() over (order by id) as rn1
        ,       row_number() over (order by id desc) as rn2
        ,       *
        from    @t
        )
select  t2.id
,       t1.name
from    numbered t1
join    numbered t2
on      t1.rn1 = t2.rn2
```

This prints:

```
id  name
4   AAA
3   BBB
2   CCC
1   DDD
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a subselect with `order by` clause for the ID column.